# Apps Script for Big query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I'm trying to connect Big Query to google sheet and using the standard apps script code. The code running without error but I don't see the result after it runs. I did below setting as well:
'd recommend trying the below steps that will help you to get rid of the error:
Clear the cache and cookies.
Try another browser or operating system.
Try an incognito or private window.
Disable browser plugins or extensions. (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Safari instructions.)
Have a domain or network administrator help you with firewall and/or server settings.
Try disabling and then re-enabling offline access.
Reset your Chrome settings.
Run Chrome Cleanup Tool, to remove software that may cause Chrome to experience issues.

Query:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to run the example code in the [BigQuery documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery), note that the function writes the results to a spreadsheet. It shows some information using the `Logger`.

```
   :
   Logger.log('Results spreadsheet created: %s',spreadsheet.getUrl());
} else {
   Logger.log('No rows returned.');
}
```

These logs are produced on the server but not in your browser. To check the messages, you must use the **View > Logs** menu.

You may check the [Logging documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) for more information.